# How to fix warning "Cypress detected that you returned a promise in a test"

Tags: cypress

I'm writing a test in cypress that checks that a new item was added to the list. I don't want to hardcode the length, I'd like to confirm that the size of the list increased by one. This code works:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/page/1');
  });

  it('happy path comments', async function() {
    cy.get('[data-cy=commentList]').should('have.length', 1);
    const list = await cy.get('[data-cy=commentList] [data-cy=comment]');
    const beforeLength = list.length;
    cy.get('[data-cy=commentBody]').type('foobar');
    cy.get('[data-cy=submit]').click();
    cy.get('.[data-cy=commentList] [data-cy=comment]').should(
      'have.length',
      beforeLength + 1
    );
    cy.get('[data-cy=commentBody]').should('have.value', '');
  });
```

However, this generates the following warning:

> cypress_runner.js:84852 Cypress Warning: Cypress detected that you
>   returned a promise in a test, but also invoked one or more cy commands
>   inside of that promise.
>
> The test title was:
>
> > Comments happy path comments
>
> While this works in practice, it's often indicative of an
>   anti-pattern. You almost never need to return both a promise and also
>   invoke cy commands.

How can I fix this warning?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Remove `async/await` from your test. Cypress commands are not promises, although behaving like promises. Read more [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values).

Also, you cannot assign or work with the return values of any Cypress command. Commands are enqueued and run asynchronously. What commands really return is Chainable, in other word, it's kind of queue object which resolves with the desired value. Read more [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values).

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Application is working fine on some machine and failing on some machines with the same reason. No `async/await` is used. And no return statement or assignment to local variable.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `Promise` to with the await keyword.  And look for more info where on w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp

- This help me out greatly

```js
// {bidderCreationRequest} was declared earlier

function createBidderObject() {
  const bidderJson = {};
  await new Promise((generateBidderObject) => {
    cy.request(bidderCreationRequest).then(async (bidderCreationResp) => {
      bidderJson.id = bidderDMCreationResp.body.id;

      generateBidderObject(bidderJson);
    });
  });

  return bidderJson.id
}

createBidderObject(); // returns the id of the recently created bidder instead of undefined/null
```

Comment: This seems like a generic answer not associated with the Cypress framework referenced in the question?